# Hide virtual keyboard when click a button

Tags: android, keyboard

Is there a way to hide the virtual keyboard once I click a button in android? The keyboard originally pops up when the user touches an edittext component; I'd like it to close once a button is pushed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to close/hide the Android Soft Keyboard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/how-to-close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 17):

Best Practice for hiding keyboard:

```
InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

It will automatically receive the current focus and will hide keyboard. Doesn't matter how many `EditText` views you have.

Answer (score 2):

**Use Below Code**

```
    your_button_id.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           try  {
             InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
             imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
           } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
          }
        }
    });
```